# Ho to fix "else if" "" is not defined?

Tags: javascript

```
{
  const Desc = data.wx_code;
  if (Desc == `0`) {
    descrp = `sunny`
  } else if (Desc == `1`) {
    descrp = `cloudy`
  }
  return {
    messages: [{text: descrp}]
  }
};
```

I get 3 error on "descrp" lines, "descrp" is not defined

Comment: So where do you define/initialize `descrp` variable? Show it.

Comment: So, what if neither `if` nor `else if` are true…?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `descrp` variable:

```
  const Desc = data.wx_code;
  let descrp = '';// default value;
  if (Desc == `0`) {
     descrp = `sunny`
  } else if (Desc == `1`) {
     descrp = `cloudy`
  }
```

or extract this code to another function:

```
{
  const Desc = data.wx_code;
  return {
    messages: [{text: computeDescription(Desc)}]
  }
};

function computeDescription(Desc){
  if (Desc == `0`) {
    return `sunny`
  } else if (Desc == `1`) {
    return `cloudy`
  }
  return ''; // default value
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can define it before the IF statement with a default value

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is, that you haven't declared `descrp` as a variable yet.

```
{
  let descrp;
  const Desc = data.wx_code;
  if (Desc == `0`) {
    descrp = `sunny`
  } else if (Desc == `1`) {
    descrp = `cloudy`
  } 
  return {
    messages: [
      {text: descrp}
    ]
  }
};
```

This should work.

Comment: you should also initialize it then

Comment: You don't have to, depends on the surrounding code IMHO. I personally prefer having `undefined` instead of an empty string as a return value for easier error and exception handling. It also helps while debugging, depending on the surrounding code `undefined` is more likely to throw an error than an empty string.